# How to export and import Portal Page in Websphere Portal 6.1.5

Tags: import, export, portal, websphere-portal

I want to setup Portal pages on my WebSphere Portal Server (WPS), which were already setup by someone else on his desktop. I have tried with the Export Portal page feature to export the Portal page from my colleague's desktop. exportPage.xml  is created. I tried importing the same on my WPS, using Import XML feature. But gives below error

> An error occurred while retrieving the resource with object ID
>   3_G5UKGAEUGB8B50A64RRL3H10N7. [portletinstance
>   5_G5UKGAEUGB8B50A64RRL3H1OO1]

The portlet reference ID which this XML is pointing to is present on my WPS.

i.e. I have deployed the same EAR ( which contains the set of portlets ) which my colleague has deployed on his WPS.

What could be the solution ?
This export / import saves a lot of time in setting up a new environment.

Comment: Do you have any theme associated to the pages?

Comment: yes. Themes and Skins were successfully exported (xmlaccess.bat) and imported

Answer (score 0):

You have to identify the issue first. 
If there is no additional information about the issue inside of 
*WAS_HOME/wp_profile/logs/WebSphere Portal/SystemOut.log* 
you should enable traces using WebSphere Portal console for XMLAccess
com.ibm.wps.services.xml.*=finest
more information should be in 
*WAS_HOME/wp_profile/logs/WebSphere Portal/trace.log* and give you more insight

I just tried similar steps without an issue. The way you used it sounds reasonable

Comment: I tried with xmlaccess.bat to import that page. It gives below error

Comment: <message id="EJPXA0129E">com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlFormatException: EJPXA0129E: An error occurred while retrieving the resource with object ID 3_G5UKGAEUGB8B50A64RRL3H10N7. [portletinstance 5_G5UKGAEUGB8B50A64RRL3H1OO1]</message>
        <message id="EJPXA0141E">com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlFormatException: EJPXA0141E: No resource could be found for object ID 3_G5UKGAEUGB8B50A64RRL3H10N7. [portletinstance 5_G5UKGAEUGB8B50A64RRL3H1OO1]</message>
    </st

Comment: looks like the objectID of the Portlet is not installed. Without the xml itself there are multiple possible options.
1. The portlet is not installed on the targeted system but you mention the Portlet is installed on your environment. You can verify it by performing a full export and check if the objectid is inside of the xml and if not check if the Portlet has a different objectid. As ObjectID's are generated during install they are different (if not explicitly provided during install)

Comment: Yes. the ObjectIDs are different. 3_G5UKGAEUGB8B50A64RRL3H10N7 is not present on my WPS. But, this is okay right. The object ID generated on another WPS is not necessary to be the same on my WPS. 
On my WPS, the ID for that portlet is 3_N2NK23640G8P00A6D3JDRH10N7. So, does it mean I have to replace all these obejctIDs from my friend's XML with those on my WPS ? 
Isn't there any other solution. 
What is the use of export and import then ?

Comment: You can create objects with a given ObjectID. This is then used for a scenario where you want to have multiple systems and you want to recreate them identical. see this link. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/admin-system/adxmlref_symbl_obj_id.dita
You have to rename the objectID, but then I would recommend to use symbolic id's if you do not have a decodable Objectid as value within the locate XMLAccess will use it only as reference during processing. 
So you would replace 3_G5UKGAEUGB8B50A64RRL3H10N7 with myPortlet inside of the XML and the system does the mapping

Comment: I tried with the <request ... create-oids="true" on the source system to create the export of the Portal Page. But it does not create the new objectIDs. The exported xml contains the same IDs as generated previously. Cann't it search using the name of the portlet instead of ID ? Can I create the request XML which will have name instead of objectIDs in <component> tag ?